# Problems compiling p0sixspwn on a raspberry pi

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, raspberry-pi

I am trying to compile p0sixspwn on a Raspberry Pi, and after installing the endless dependencies (libimobiledevice <1.1.0, libusbmuxd, etc.) I successfully ran ./autogen.sh but when I tried running "make", I was met with the following errors (yes I am running as root):

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/p0sixspwn# make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/p0sixspwn'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/p0sixspwn/src'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -I../include -fPIC  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/libxml2   -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/libxml2   -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/lib/libzip/include    -g -O2 -c -o pris0nbarake-idevicebackup2.o `test -f 'idevicebackup2.c' || echo './'`idevicebackup2.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -I../include -fPIC  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/libxml2   -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/libxml2   -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/lib/libzip/include    -g -O2 -c -o pris0nbarake-jailbreak.o `test -f 'jailbreak.c' || echo './'`jailbreak.c
In file included from jailbreak.c:56:0:
MobileDevice.h:193:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:207:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:229:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:241:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:258:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:258:61: error: unknown type name ‘CFStringRef’
MobileDevice.h:262:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:262:72: error: unknown type name ‘CFStringRef’
In file included from jailbreak.c:56:0:
MobileDevice.h:271:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:386:1: error: unknown type name ‘CFMutableDictionaryRef’
MobileDevice.h:386:54: error: unknown type name ‘CFAllocatorRef’
MobileDevice.h:412:11: error: unknown type name ‘CFDictionaryRef’
MobileDevice.h:414:11: error: unknown type name ‘CFDictionaryRef’
MobileDevice.h:419:44: error: unknown type name ‘CFStringRef’
MobileDevice.h:420:5: error: unknown type name ‘CFStringRef’
MobileDevice.h:420:36: error: unknown type name ‘CFStringRef’
MobileDevice.h:421:15: error: unknown type name ‘CFStringRef’
MobileDevice.h:421:47: error: unknown type name ‘CFStringRef’
MobileDevice.h:422:54: error: unknown type name ‘CFStringRef’
MobileDevice.h:426:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:427:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:428:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:429:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:430:1: error: unknown type name ‘CFStringRef’
MobileDevice.h:430:71: error: unknown type name ‘CFStringRef’
MobileDevice.h:431:1: error: unknown type name ‘CFStringRef’
MobileDevice.h:433:33: error: unknown type name ‘CFStringRef’
MobileDevice.h:435:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:435:57: error: unknown type name ‘CFStringRef’
MobileDevice.h:435:84: error: unknown type name ‘CFStringRef’
MobileDevice.h:436:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:436:51: error: unknown type name ‘CFStringRef’
MobileDevice.h:437:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:437:54: error: unknown type name ‘notify_callback’
MobileDevice.h:438:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:441:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:442:1: error: unknown type name ‘mach_error_t’
MobileDevice.h:442:57: error: unknown type name ‘CFMutableDictionaryRef’
MobileDevice.h:482:5: error: unknown type name ‘CFDictionaryRef’
jailbreak.c:417:1: error: unknown type name ‘kern_return_t’
jailbreak.c:417:51: error: unknown type name ‘CFPropertyListRef’
jailbreak.c:418:1: error: unknown type name ‘CFPropertyListRef’
jailbreak.c:422:24: error: unknown type name ‘CFDataRef’
jailbreak.c: In function ‘cb2’:
jailbreak.c:481:9: error: unknown type name ‘CFStringRef’
jailbreak.c:483:9: error: unknown type name ‘UniChar’
jailbreak.c:505:9: error: unknown type name ‘CFPropertyListRef’
jailbreak.c:505:36: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
jailbreak.c:506:9: error: unknown type name ‘CFMutableDictionaryRef’
jailbreak.c:506:75: error: ‘kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks’ undeclared (first use in this function)
jailbreak.c:506:75: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
jailbreak.c:506:107: error: ‘kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks’ undeclared (first use in this function)
jailbreak.c:518:113: error: ‘kCFAllocatorNull’ undeclared (first use in this function)
jailbreak.c:533:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strstr’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/string.h:342:14: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
jailbreak.c: In function ‘stroke_lockdownd’:
jailbreak.c:562:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘idevice_connection_send’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
../include/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice.h:94:17: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘uint32_t *’
jailbreak.c:565:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘idevice_connection_receive_timeout’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
../include/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice.h:95:17: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned int *’
jailbreak.c:569:9: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘idevice_connection_receive_timeout’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
../include/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice.h:95:17: note: expected ‘uint32_t’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned int *’
Makefile:413: recipe for target 'pris0nbarake-jailbreak.o' failed
make[2]: *** [pris0nbarake-jailbreak.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/p0sixspwn/src'
Makefile:340: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/p0sixspwn'
Makefile:271: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/p0sixspwn#
```

I have googled "error: unknown type name" but to me this seemed to mean different things for different stuff (I may be wrong though).

Here is what it said after I ran ./autogen.sh in case it is of any importance:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/p0sixspwn# ./autogen.sh
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
libtoolize: linking file `./ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `m4'.
libtoolize: linking file `m4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: linking file `m4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: linking file `m4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: linking file `m4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: linking file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
libtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
configure.ac:10: installing `./compile'
configure.ac:7: installing `./config.guess'
configure.ac:7: installing `./config.sub'
configure.ac:8: installing `./install-sh'
configure.ac:8: installing `./missing'
gui/Makefile.am: installing `./depcomp'
libtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
checking build system type... armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking host system type... armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking target system type... armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... none
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf file names to armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... none
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for libimobiledevice... yes
checking for libplist... yes
checking for libzip... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating gui/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/p0sixspwn#
```

I currently do not have the option to install it on another computer.
This is also my first post so I am a noob.
If anybody could help that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it is not possible to compile p0sixspwn on the Raspberry Pi (or any Linux distribution) at the moment. It is hard to compile it on a mac, and even harder on Windows.

If there was some way to get Wine working on the Raspberry Pi, or editing the source code, then it might be possible. But for now, it is not.

EDIT:
It is sort of possible. Compile CFLite and include that. There will be a couple errors, but you can figure it out pretty easily.